# Lightning issues

Tags: lightning-experience, change-set, migration

We are getting following error in migration to another sandbox:

> Unknown permission

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's "Lightning", not "Lightening".

Answer (score 0):

On the target sandbox Click on Setup and on the left you would see Lightning experience. Click on that and if you scroll to the bottom of the page on the right hand side there will be a switch to enable lightning experience. Once you enable it try the deployment again.
[image]

Comment: Thanks RedDevil, Will it give permission to all profiles

Comment: Once Enable, can it be reverted back too

Comment: Yes its an org wide setting it gives permission to all profiles. Yes the same switch can be used to disable it as well. Also Once its enabled at the user level a user can switch between Lightning experience and Classic as they wish. This user level option comes when they click they username in salesforce(right top)